# How to change index.html (firebase hosting) to show project content?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-hosting, react-native-web

I'm a react-native beginner and I tried to host my project but ended up with a launched web app showing a firebase welcome screen. This is because of the index.html generated when doing init firebase. The index.html file looks like this:

[image]

How do I replace the Index.html with my own front-end code? I have an index.js file; is this somehow related?

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

When you run

`firebase init`

from within your project folder, then Select

> Use an existing project

then select the folder where you own index.html is (typically ./build) and say No to overwrite.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this but when it created the build folder it gave me an index.html with a welcome screen (attached picture of index.html code). I had no index.html before init so there was nothing to overwrite. I'm left with this file in the build folder and no clue how to make it show my project front end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this problem as well. What I found is best is to delete the whole directory and everything in it and restart. When you restart, DO NOT overwrite any of the files with code from firebase hosting. You can just implement the firebase hosting code later without messing anything up. Sorry this response might be late but I hope it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

IDK if you have found a solution but basically once you've ran the command 'firebase init hosting' the index.html file and the firebase.json file are created in the selected directory you can change the file that is used to display the front end in the firebase.json file like this

firebase.json file before:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

firebase.json file after:

```
{
 "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.js"
      }
    ]
 }
}
```